# Unable to do a variable reference “inside” another variable when using ssh

Tags: bash, shell, virtual-machine

I have written a shell script, which when run on one vm,collects the status of various other services input by the user from different vms.The code is as follows

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
echo -e "\n Please pass the service names in the command line argument\n"
exit 1
fi

cl=$#
HOSTS="IP address of hosts"

for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS}
do
         echo -e "Service status on $HOSTNAME"

         ssh root@$HOSTNAME bash -c '
                  for ((i=1;i<='$cl';i++))
                  do
                     echo $i
                     eval x='\$$i'

                     echo $x
                     service $i  status
                     done                                       '
done
```

While using `eval x='\$$i'` the value of 'x' is supposed to be the argument passed by the user, but when I ssh it , the value is not getting interpreted, instead the value of x is $.

The value of x should be $1,$2 and so on.....based on the value of i.

For example if I give **./test.sh sssd**, then the value of **x** should be **sssd**

Answer (score 0):

I've quote several variables which should be quote.

Please check the below code

```
for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS}
do
         echo -e "Service status on $HOSTNAME"

         ssh root@"$HOSTNAME" bash -c '
                  for ((i=1;i<='"$cl"';i++))
                  do
                     echo $i
                     eval x='$$i'

                     echo $x
                     service $i  status
                     done                                       '
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler if you just don't try to reuse the value of `i` as a positional parameter.

```
ssh root@"$HOSTNAME" bash -c '
  i=0
  for x in "$@"; do
    echo "$i"
    echo "$x"
    service "$i" status
    i=$((i+1))
  done
' _ "$@"
```

Note that you need to pass `test.sh`'s arguments to `ssh` as well to ensure they are passed along to the `bash` script on the remote end. `_` is a dummy argument to set the (unused) value of `$0` in your script.

Or, use indirect parameter expansion instead of `eval`:

```
ssh root@$HOSTNAME bash -c '
  for ((i=1;i<='$cl';i++))
  do
     echo "$i"
     x=${!i}
     echo "$x"
     service "$i" status
  done
' _ "$@"
```